# How to preallocate memory for a constantly concatenated array in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, concatenation, signal-processing, dynamic-memory-allocation

I want to create a Hankel matrix of size 50x510 (for the example snippet given below) using **SingalN** which a sinusoidal data of size **N**.  The Hankel matrix is created with first 100 elements of **SignalN** and then next hundred is concatenated horizontal to the previously created Hankel matrix and so on until **d=9**.  Since the matrix is constantly changing size, how can I allocate memory here and is there any better way to do this is MATLAB?

```
L = 50; 
N = 1000;
D = 10;
M = (N/D)-L+1;
H_global  = zeros(L,M*D);
for d = 0:D-1
    temp = 100*d;
    H = hankel(SignalN(temp+1:temp+L),SignalN(temp+L:100*(d+1)));
    if d == 0
        H_global = H;
    else
        H_global = horzcat(H_global,H);
    end
end
```

Comment: `H_global  = zeros(L,M*D);` this allocates memory. Allocate all the memory you need, and index, instead of concatenate. In fact, you dont use this at all, so you allocate the required memory, but then overwrite it.

Comment: Thank you, I did not think about indexing.